# add bool column within existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to dd a column, to a database with the program Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I already have a database, with a table, in that table i need to add another column.. but it keeps saying it cannot find type bool or boolean.

my code :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD IsOpen boolean GO
```

Any ideas ?

side question, any idea how to alter an existing column ? i have a column called "budget" but it needs to be "Budget".

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD IsOpen bit GO` - The equivalent is a bit field.

Comment: ALTER TABLE table_name ADD IsOpen `bit`. 1 is true, 0 is false

Comment: well that was fast...

Comment: easy reputation points, all these answers are the same...its like copy and paste

Comment: any idea for the 2nd. side qustion about rename column ?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE budget Budget DATATYPE;` for your extra question....NB: add your datatype e.g(`varchar(50)`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `bit` instead of `bool` datatype

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD IsOpen bit
 GO
```

**Here some info about datatypes**

```
Data type   Access  SQLServer   Oracle  MySQL   PostgreSQL
boolean     Yes/No   Bit         Byte   N/A      Boolean
```

**Answer for Qustion 2**

The syntax to rename a column in an existing table in SQL Server (Transact-SQL) is:

**Syntax:**

```
sp_rename 'table_name.old_column_name', 'new_column_name', 'COLUMN';
```

**For your column :**

```
sp_rename 'table_name.budget', 'Budget', 'COLUMN';
```

Answer (score 3):

bit (0/1) is used as boolean in SQL

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD IsOpen bit GO
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableX] ADD IsOpen bit
```

Comment: any idea for the 2nd. question ? the "side question"

Answer (score 2):

In mssql there is no type called `boolean` or `bool`. You have to use `bit`, which is 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2):

The answers here are good but there's a best practice that I'm surprised hasn't been mentioned. I would recommend making all new boolean/bit columns `NOT NULL`.

By allowing null values, the value you're storing can be true, false, or null. In many boolean cases, having a third value (null) doesn't make sense and has the potential to cause unforeseen bugs.

This is the SQL script I would recommend for creating bit/boolean columns:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD IsOpen bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
GO
```

This will not allow null values and will default records to have a 1/true value. If you expect your data to be false/0 by default, then just change the 1 here to a 0.